# How can i put label into the table cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilabel

[image: table cell]

this is the cell i want to make the left side is cell.text and the right part is label.
Now the table style is

UITableViewStyleGrouped When i try to make the label i write these codes.

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"All";
UIView* view = cell.contentView;
UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
label1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label1.text = @"%15";
[view addSubview:label1];
[label1 release];
```

But this doesnt work because cell of the label cover one and another.Can any one help me to make this kind of look with code of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code seems to be the *label1's* frame. Change the its frame like the following.

```
CGRect lFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.width - 100, 0, 100, cell.frame.height);
UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lFrame];
```

---

**Using exisiting style:** The style you are using is already predefined. No need to add your custom label to the cell. You can achieve this style by specifying table cell's style to **UITableViewCellStyleValue1**.

```
[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 ....
```

You can change the font properties like style, color and size of the cell's *textLabel* and *detailedTextLabel* to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your UITableviewCell type to UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and do like below.

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"All";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"%15";
```

You don't need to add view in the cell at all. Also, you can change textLable and DetailTextLabel properties whatever you want as you change with UILabel. They are UILabel itself. So you can do everything whatever you can do with UILabel.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-defined styles are great if they cover your needs.

Otherwise an approach like this one will work for cases where you want more power over the layout, or more views in the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self makeCell: CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyData *data =  [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    lbl1.text = data.text;
    lbl2.text = data.auxText;    

    return cell;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)makeLensListCell: (NSString *)identifier
{
    CGRect lbl1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 140, 25);
    CGRect lbl2Frame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 140, 25);

    UILabel *lbl;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

    // Label with tag 1.
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl1Frame];
    lbl.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];

    // Label with tag 2.
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl2Frame];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];

    // Add as many labels and other views as you like

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: well tobehonest i am going to write something like that beacause i have like 100 cell :)